# Java swing gridbaglayout does not fill complete frame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to build a component similar to a JProgressBar which would show three states instead of two as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxPle.png).

I have built this by adding three JLabel components(with three different background colors) to a panel with layout set as GridBagLayout. I have assigned corresponding weights to these labels, so that they get resized according to the size of the parent panel. Below is the corresponding sample code:

```
public class CustomProgressBar {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    double firstLabelWeight = 0.10d;
    double secondLabelWeight = 0.20d;
    double thirdLabelWeight = 1d - firstLabelWeight - secondLabelWeight;

    JLabel firstLabel = new JLabel();
    firstLabel.setOpaque(true);
    firstLabel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    JLabel secondLabel = new JLabel();
    secondLabel.setOpaque(true);
    secondLabel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    JLabel thirdLabel = new JLabel();
    thirdLabel.setOpaque(true);
    thirdLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    gbc.weightx = firstLabelWeight;
    gbc.weighty = 1d;
    panel.add(firstLabel, gbc);

    gbc.weightx = secondLabelWeight;
    gbc.weighty = 1d;
    panel.add(secondLabel, gbc);

    gbc.weightx = thirdLabelWeight;
    gbc.weighty = 1d;
    panel.add(thirdLabel, gbc);

    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(157, 50));

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Now the problem with this approach is that when I try to resize the JFrame, the above three labels are not filling the complete horizontal space in the parent panel and we see black strips to the ends of the panel as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egbC5.png).

[image]

I have tried setting gbc.fill and gbc.anchor parameters as well, but it still doesn't work.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated! Thankyou :)

Comment: It seems to be a rounding problem. When setting the initial width to 160, there are no black bars on the left or right side. They appear/disappear when resizing slowly.

Comment: The black stripe is there due to rounding errors. The width of the parent panel is always integer amount of pixels. When distributing them to particular components the layout manager ends up with some extra pixels it doesn't know where to put. This is just how the GridBagLayout works. If this is a serious issue for you you will have to override GridBagLayout.

Comment: Take a look at [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107011/java-extra-pixels-at-the-bottom-of-jframe-gridbaglayout?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) it deals with similar problem you have.

Comment: @MatheM The related link does solve my problem. Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to overcome the rounding problems, you could override the layout for the panel in this way:

```
class MyLayout extends GridBagLayout
{
  private Component owner;

  public MyLayout(Component owner)
  {
    this.owner = owner;
  }

  @Override
  protected void adjustForGravity(GridBagConstraints constraints,
                                  Rectangle          rect)
  {
    // Adjust position and width of first (GREEN) label if necessary
    if ((rect.x > 0) && (rect.x <= 2))
    {
      rect.width += rect.x;
      rect.x = 0;
    }

    // Adjust width of last (RED) label if necessary
    int gap = owner.getWidth() - rect.x - rect.width;
    if ((gap > 0) && (gap <= 2))
      rect.width += gap;
  }

} // class MyLayout
```

Then of course, set the layout of the panel in this way:

```
panel.selLayout(new MyLayout(panel));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you construct the `GridBagConstraints` providing negative `Insets`, this will not show the underlying `Panel`. The change will be the following

> GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(-1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 10, 0, new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0, 0);

**Updated Example:**

```
public class CustomProgressBar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    double firstLabelWeight = 0.10d;
    double secondLabelWeight = 0.20d;
    double thirdLabelWeight = 1d - firstLabelWeight - secondLabelWeight;

    JLabel firstLabel = new JLabel();
    firstLabel.setOpaque(true);
    firstLabel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    JLabel secondLabel = new JLabel();
    secondLabel.setOpaque(true);
    secondLabel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    JLabel thirdLabel = new JLabel();
    thirdLabel.setOpaque(true);
    thirdLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(-1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 10, 0, new Insets(-1, -1, -1, -1), 0, 0);

    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    gbc.weightx = firstLabelWeight;
    gbc.weighty = 1d;
    panel.add(firstLabel, gbc);

    gbc.weightx = secondLabelWeight;
    gbc.weighty = 1d;
    panel.add(secondLabel, gbc);

    gbc.weightx = thirdLabelWeight;
    gbc.weighty = 1d;
    panel.add(thirdLabel, gbc);

    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(157, 50));

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Even easier: create default constraints "gbc = new GridBagConstraints()" and then only set the horizontal Insets "gbc.insets = new Insets(0, -1, 0, -1)".

Comment: Although this approach is simple and fills the complete panel, there is an issue when one of the labels has to fill the complete panel. For instance, in the above example making the weight of first and second label as zero should fill the complete panel with the third label which is red, but we see a strip of green at the beginning.